# Selenium - is not reachable by keyboard python

Tags: python, selenium

```
birthday = driver.find_element_by_name("date_of_birth_day")
birthday.send_keys("11092000")
birthday.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

When I run this code I get

```
"input class=" web-date-input__form-input" name="date_of_birth_day" type="number"> is not 
 reachable by keyboard"
```

but the element is "Keyboard-Focusable"

```
input class="web-date-input__form-input" type="number" placeholder="DD" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2" max="31" min="1" name="date_of_birth_day" tabindex="3" data-testid="input-birthday-day" value="11".
```

I do not understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve it by just sending the keys without an element, I am not sure it will work in any case but it worked for me.

```
import actions = ActionChains(driver)
  actions.send_keys("11092000")
  actions.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  actions.perform()
```